# The listview is not clickable

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Though I create a clickable listveiw before, at that time I can not do the same.
I am using fragment activity.

This is my fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Arriving" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Departure" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pax" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tbrow"
                android:text="Phone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/room_type" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rate" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lview"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="318dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dim_dark"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:transitionGroup="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1">

    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here this is my context xml or do not know how it is called. But data or items in that xml . Textviews are receving data (reservation info from the url ) .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:clickable="false">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/namev"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkv"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/depv"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/personv"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phonev"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailv"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/roomtypev"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ratev"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here this is activity codes. I tried implement also "AdapterView.OnItemClickListener".

```
public class Res extends Fragment  {
    ListView lv;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_res, container, false);
        lv = view.findViewById(R.id.lview);
        lv.setClickable(true);

        getReservations();


        return view;
    }

public void parseItems(String jsonResponse) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");


            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                final String name = jo.getString("name");
                final String phone = jo.getString("phone");
                final String email = jo.getString("email");
                final String arriving = jo.getString("arriving");
                final String departure = jo.getString("departure");
                final String pax = jo.getString("pax");
                final String roomtype = jo.getString("roomtype");
                final String rate = jo.getString("rate");


                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                item.put("name", name);
                item.put("email", email);
                item.put("phone", phone);
                item.put("arriving", arriving);
                item.put("departure", departure);
                item.put("pax", pax);
                item.put("roomtype", roomtype);
                item.put("rate", rate);


                list.add(item);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.getres,
                new String[]{"name", "phone", "email", "arriving", "departure", "pax", "roomtype", "rate"}, new int[]{R.id.namev, R.id.phonev, R.id.emailv, R.id.checkv, R.id.depv, R.id.personv, R.id.roomtypev, R.id.ratev});

        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);


        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        loading.dismiss();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("TAG", "CLICKED row number: ");

            }
        });


    }
```

I am not receiving any error.But I can not make my lisview clickable either.
If it is necessary I can post entire activity code.

Comment: remove `android:clickable="true"' and `android:focusable="true"` and `android:longClickable="true"` from your Listview

Comment: the same unfortunately

Comment: Do you want to make the items inside the ListView clickable?

Comment: yes exactly that is I want to